# Objective-C - Initializing an already initialized object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

What happens if I call `[alloc] init]` on an object which already was initialized and alloc'ed?

In my particular case I have an `NSMutableArray` which I initialize in superclass `Parent` using `NSMutableArray* someArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

In subclass `Child` I need to insert an object in `someArray` but at a specific index, for example 3.
So if the array has no items, or if it has less items than the index I'm trying to insert at (array has 4 items, and I want to insert at index 10) it will crash.

What would happen if I initialized `someArray` again in `Child` class? Would the pointer stored in `someArray` be replaced with the new one I'm initializing and the "old" one would just leak?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, my terminology was a bit off. I don't mean doing `[someObject alloc]`, but doing `someObject = [SomeClass alloc] init];` where `someObject` had previoulsy been initialized with an instance of `SomeClass`

Comment: Neither, it would just crash with an `unrecognized selector` exception - `+ alloc` is not an instance method.

Comment: i don't mean calling `alloc` on `someArray`, i mean doing `someArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000]`, for example, where `someArray` had already been initialized in a parent class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for clarity when you say "What happens if I call `[alloc] init]` on an object..." your terminology is wrong.

The following line:

```
NSMutableArray* someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Reads in English:

"Send the `alloc` message to the `NSMutableArray` class object, then send the `init` message to the object returned from the first message, then store the object returned from `init` into the pointer variable named `someArray`."

I say that to emphasize the fact that you're not "calling alloc/init" on an existing object, you're making a new object, and storing a reference to this new object over the reference you had to the previous object. Since you no longer have a reference to that previous object, you've lost the ability to properly release its memory, so yes, you'll leak it.

Answer (score 4):

correct, it will leak. Use NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex‎:

Comment: i'm using this right now and it crashes when the array's capacity is, for example 4 and i try to insert at index 10

Comment: you have to check the array bounds first and either insert empty objects or add at the end of the array. C isn't a scripting language, the array won't auto expand

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways that come to mind to do what I think you want.  A sort of clumsy one is to put as many `[NSNull null]` objects into the array as you need so that it's filled up to the spot where you need to add the new object.  Then you would replace an existing `NSNull` if you were storing your own object.

Probably a better approach is to use a dictionary instead of an array and turn your index value into a key.

Comment: yeah, this is what i ended up doing but i just wanted to know if the pointers where replaced and the memory was leaked or if the compiler did something else behind the scenes

Comment: I believe `[NSNull null]` is a singleton, so there are no extra copies to leak...and even if there were copies, only the array is doing any retaining so removing them wouldn't leak.